# How to fix "DocumentDB data migration tool "

Tags: migration, amazon-dynamodb, azure-cosmosdb, data-migration

I'm using DocumentDB data migration tool for Migration of AWS DynamoDB data to Azure CosmosDB but I'm getting an error for the large table data.

It seems DocumentDB data migration tool has a maximum capacity for data transfer is 500k bytes but I have a dynamo DB table which has data around 315 Mb.
So there is any other methods/tools for data transfer from Dynamo DB to cosmos DB?

I also tried to convert the dynamo DB into JSON file and upload it to the cosmos DB collection but cosmos DB collection take max size is 2mb.
In image2 showing error only for large data file while I tried for the file less than the size of 500k bytes, it worked properly.

Preview stage

[image: X]

Error image

[image: Y]

Comment: Don't know anything about this problem... but there is a "Technical details" thing... didn't you click it?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: So,does my answer helps you?

Comment: @JayGong Yes your answer helps for small amount of data.
I was transfering about 40 GB of data from dynamo DB to Cosmos DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had around 40 GB of data in dyanamo DB and wanted to move it to Cosmos DB.
But cosmos DB has some limitation that while direct copying will won't allow json data size more than 2 mb.

I used same tool and coverted the DynamoDB data into json format and store on server, once it is completed i uploaded that json data to cosmos DB using same DocumentDB Data Migration Tool.

**Thanks for your responses.**

Answer (score 0):

> So there is any other methods/tools for data transfer from Dynamo DB
>   to cosmos DB?

Seems that you was trapped by the limitation of Cosmos DB.Since you could convert the data into json files,maybe you could consider following way.

1.Store the json files into [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=windows).

2.Use Azure Data Factory Data Factory [Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) to transfer data from [blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage) to [cosmos db](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db).

I could have anticipated that you might encounter performance bottleneck with the large data,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#considerations-for-the-source).

If you still can't make the transmission smoothly, I suggest you fragmenting json files with code so that it can't be more than 2MB.

Tips: By the way, you could vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/17544724-add-amazon-dynamodb-data-source) to push the progress of adding Amazon DynamoDb Data Source in Azure Data Factory.

Thanks.